# How to load a pdf file from Application Directory in flutter?

Tags: pdf, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to load a PDF file from the application directory, I tried loading it from the url  and it works and no I need to load the already downloaded PDF from the Application directory.

This is the package that I used to view PDF `flutter_pdfview`, while trying to load it from a url this works fine, now what I need is load an already downloaded pdf from the directory.

for loading file from directory i tried this:

```
var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
File file = File('${dir.path}/$pName.pdf');

bool  fileExists = File(await '${dir.path}/$pName.pdf')
                  .existsSync();

             if(fileExists)
                {
                  urlPdfPath = file.toString();
                  print('url pdf path $urlPdfPath');
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return PdfViewer(
                      path: urlPdfPath,
                      product: pName,
                    );
                  }));

                }
```

when i run this i got the exception

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 4565): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 4565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4565): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
```

Comment: what exact issue are you facing doing in this .? - Get the directory path - `var _dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();` then get the file - `File _file = File("${_dir.path}/$fileName.pdf");` then pass the `_file` to PDFviewer which you are using.

Comment: I had done this but this throws an exception unable to open.

Comment: paste your code & PDF package you are using & you didn't mention the error in question also.  How can anybody help without that .?

Comment: @anmol.majhail I had updated my question please have a look

Comment: @anmol.majhail that code works perfectly, that code is used to load pdf form url and get(url) function is a method inside http package.

Comment: @anmol.majhail i'm not sure about that it shows `Instance of 'Response'` , i think it is not String(url);

Comment: @anmol.majhail I think you are still talking about the working code. I will remove the working code from the question.

Comment: isn't - `urlPdfPath = file.toString();`  should be `urlPdfPath = file.path;`

Comment: @anmol.majhail Thanks a lot, that works. Can you add this as answer so that i can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Code:

Change - `urlPdfPath = file.toString();` to  `urlPdfPath = file.path;`